# Highchart live server example uses a lot cpu

Tags: javascript, sqlite, highcharts

I have an embedded linux system witch collects some data and puts it in a SQLite database. New data is added every second. I would like to get this data out of the database and plot it live in a chart with `highchart`. So every second a new point needs to be added to the chart.

I used the following example as a starting point: http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm

It works but when I visit the page my cpu uses 50% (I use chrome). Even 100% if I plot morge graphs. Even with the live server example I can see my cpu usage rising. I tried searching for an awnser but couldn't find anything. Is this the best way? or is this a bug or am I missing something? Here is some of my code:

```
function request_accu_Data() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'live-accu-data.php', 
        success: function(point) {
            var accu_series = accu_chart.series[0];
                shift = accu_series.data.length > 100; // shift if the series is longer than 100

            // add the point
            accu_chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(request_accu_Data, 500); 
        },
        cache: false
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    accu_chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'Accu_graph_container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: request_accu_Data
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
             formatter: function() {

              return false;
               }
        },
            title: {
            text: 'Accu level'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.9,
            maxPadding: 0.9,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: '%',
                margin: 10
            }
        },
        series: [{
            //pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
            name: 'Accu level',
            data: [
            ]
        }]
    });
```

The php code looks like this:

```
<?php 
// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");


$db = new PDO('sqlite:/home/pi/client.db');
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1');
foreach($result as $row){
    $ret = intval( $row['Timestamp'])*1000;
    $ret2= intval( $row['Accu_level']);
}

$tot = array($ret,$ret2);

echo json_encode($tot);
?>
```

I really hope you can help me!

Comment: How much does your CPU go up when viewing the demo? What kind of CPU do you have? I have an i5-3450 @ 3.10Ghz, idling around 1-6%, with a max of 12% and average of 9% when viewing the demo.

Comment: Do you know whether it's the browser or the back end which is taking all thetime ? Is it possible that it's the select statement taking all the time ?

Comment: Thanks for your commands! I have an intel-2415M @ 2.3GHz. When viewing the live server example the cpu usage goes up by about 8% (only one line is draw) but on my own page I plot like 8 lines and its using 100%. The server is a raspberry pi with lighttpd. The back end is a macbook running mint browser is chrome.

Comment: Sorry, a raspberry pi is not a server. IT's a fun hobbist tool, but it is not a server. You're also not making sense when you say `the backend is a macbook running mint browser`. But, you say your 'server' (backend) is a raspberry pi... Which is it?

Comment: which machine is running 100% CPI, the raspberry pi or the macbook ?

Comment: Sorry that was confusing indeed. I use the Raspberry to log some environment data en run a lighttp server. When I visit the webpage on my macbook (running linux mint. Browser is chrome) the CPU of the macbook goes wild. The CPU of the Raspi is about idle.

Comment: Did some more debugging and if I comment out the accu_chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift); line in the request_accu_Data() function, the CPU is not going crazy. There used to be a bug (http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11250) but this is supposed to be fixed right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only things I can think of to suggest are:

1. Poll the server less often. You are polling every 500 ms at the moment.
2. Disable animation in highcharts.
3. If you are adding points to more than 1 series add each one without redrawing the chart, and then redraw at the end.

Note, to disable animation, you need to set:

```
animation:false
```

in the chart definition, but you also need to disable it in the addPoint call.

```
accu_chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! But it's not really helping much. I changed the polling time to 1000 This helped a little bit but I can't go any slower because I need it realtime.

Comment: Did you try disablin animation ?

Comment: Yes I did. But the only difference I see is when the page first loads the line isn't animated. After loading I see no difference.

Comment: Added comment to only redraw after each series has been updated.

Comment: Have you disabled animation in the addPoint call ?

Comment: SteveP thank you!:) It was indeed the animation in the addPoint call. Only when I use your line of code the animations where not disabled. I used:
accu_chart.redraw(false); 
Now it's working perfect! Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but I suggest you to not use MySQL for this kind of data. Get a look to Timestore, a mix between RRD and noSQL concept : http://www.mike-stirling.com/redmine/projects/timestore
I use it for a project, and it's very fast and CPU efficient.